# Package python libraries

Tags: python

I have many servers I would like to run my python files on.

Unfortunately not all have the libraries I need, and I have no rights to install anything on the servers.

Is there a way to use a jar or similar to package the libraries I need and be able to execute the file without those libraries installed?

Comment: There are tons of tools to address the problem, from virtual environments to Docker containers. Do you have any specific constraints preventing their use?

Comment: Yeah we have loads of servers which we parallelize our jobs over but we have no rights to install anything on any of them. Only to run our scripts. So we can't do that:(

Comment: Start here - https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: @kikee1222 virtual environments do not require any of these. The project environment is just an extra folder with all the dependencies, which is added to import paths. It can be simply copied if the hardware platform and OS are similar enough

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you do not have user right permissions you cannot install any of them. but there is another way to use the conda package manger to pack the conda environenmt to unzip it where ever you need it.

https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

basically, build your conda env in your admin rights PC, then pack into TAR ball, then use the same link to zip out and play it.

Just one Silly method: try to open the CMD in RUn as administrator , if it is opening, the you can isntall it without any issues.

Comment: Note: Conda is developed and tested with Windows, and only Windows, in mind - and, perhaps, is the best of Windows options. On Linux, however, it leads to most obscure errors even with popular packages.